# Content Query Web Part does not appear in mobile view

Tags: 2013, calendar, content-query-web-part, hyperlink, mobile-view

I have successfully created several CQWPs on our intranet homepage to pull announcements from team sites as well as list events on Community calendar. These can all be viewed on the desktop, laptop, tablet or iPad.

However, when I view the intranet site on my phone nothing appears under the CQWPs or the calendar.

My current workaround is to copy and paste the text/links to the home page which will become very time-consuming. Not only that I lose the benefit of having the new item notification appear in the link and have been copying and pasting the image. But cannot do the same for the Calendar.

Any suggestions would be helpful.